# How to find a string from 3 known words?

Tags: php, html

I am finding a word from random strings of paragraphs.

```
  <head>
<style>
  * {padding-top:10px; margin:0;}
  body {overflow:hidden;}
</style>

<script src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/V6NfEzT7.js"></script>
    </head>
   <center> <body>
<div id="player"></div>
    <script>
        jwplayer('player').setup({
    sources: [{
      file: "rtmp://163.172.67.164:80/live",
      file: "http://163.172.67.164/live/chsix/index.mp4?dsgfsdksdfbjdbfsdfsdkfs121413r"
    }],
    width: "60%",
    aspectratio: "16:9",
    hlshtml: true
  });
</script>
   <!-- Histats.com  (div with counter) --><div id="histats_counter"></div>
  <!-- Histats.com  START  (aync)-->
   <script type="text/javascript">var _Hasync= _Hasync|| [];
  _Hasync.push(['Histats.startgif', '1,3597882,4,10045,"div#histatsC {position: absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}body>div#histatsC {position: fixed;}"']);
  _Hasync.push(['Histats.fasi', '1']);
  _Hasync.push(['Histats.track_hits', '']);
  (function() {
  var hs = document.createElement('script'); hs.type = 'text/javascript';       hs.async = true;
 hs.src = ('//s10.histats.com/js15_gif_as.js');
 (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ||     document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(hs);
 })();</script>
<noscript><a href="/" alt="" target="_blank" ><div id="histatsC"><img    border="0" src="http://s4is.histats.com/stats/i/3597882.gif?3597882&103"></div></a>
```

I want to find "http://163.172.67.164/live/chsix/index.mp4?dsgfsdksdfbjdbfsdfsdkfs121413r".
The known unique word is "mp4". Can I find the "mp4" position and after find the double quotes positions forward and backward? Is it possible?

My a little effort is:

```
  $html_encoded = htmlentities($text);

  $pos = strpos($html_encoded, ".mp4");
  $pos1 = strpos($html_encoded, '"');

  echo substr($html_encoded,$pos-50,100)."<br>";
```

But it is meaningless to find  the whole double quoted sentence. Please kindly suggest me to solve it.

Comment: what exactly do you want to output to be?

Comment: wanna print this line - "http://163.172.67.164/live/chsix/index.mp4?dsgfsdksdfbjdbfsdfsdkfs121413r"

Comment: Please consider posting an example of the 'string paragraph' that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...see embedded comments.  $z returns your desired string, "163.172.167.164/live/chsix/".

```
$x = "http://163.172.67.164/live/chsix/index.mp4?dsgfsdksdfbjdbfsdfsdkfs121413r";
$y = parse_url($x);                       //create associative array that can be manipulated$y_exploded = explode('/', $y['path']);   //break the path into an array
array_pop($y_exploded);                   //remove index.mp4
$y_imploded = implode('/', $y_exploded);  //glue the path back together
$z = $y['host'].$y_imploded.'/';
```

Comment: No, it won't. I want to output the whole line "http://163.172.67.164/live/chsix/index.mp4?dsgfsdksdfbjdbfsdfsdkfs121413r" from the paragraph. The known word is .mp4 in the whole string and find between two quotes words that contain the konwn word "mp4".

Comment: What is the "paragraph"?  It would help if you would post that string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php   
  $link = "http://163.172.67.164/live/chsix/index.mp4?dsgfsdksdfbjdbfsdfsdkfs121413r";
  // Break string on ".mp4" using explode
  $break_first = explode(".mp4", $link );
  // find last slash(/) position from above string
  $last_slash = strrpos($break_first[0],'/');
  $result = substr($break_first[0], 0, $last_slash);
?>
```